# Custom Permalink Plugin and Current Page/Ancestor in Menus

Tags: plugins, menus, permalinks

I'm looking for a custom permalink plugin that is able to interact with menu classes.

For instance, I have a menu that includes the parent `website.com/shop` as one of its list items. If a page, say `website.com/shop/product`, includes that menu, the list item for `website.com/shop` will get a class, something like `current-page-ancestor`. This is useful for styling that link so users know what section of the website they are on.

But I will have pages whose parent will not be `website.com/shop` (a feature I can't change), but I want it to appear that `website.com/shop` is the parent. For instance, the page is `website.com/foo/product-2`. I'm currently using the [Custom Permalinks plugin](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/custom-permalinks) to change the permalink to `website.com/shop/product-2`. But in doing this, the menu does not recognize that `website.com/shop` is the parent, and no class is added to the menu's list item.

Is there any workaround for this, or does anyone know of a custom permalinks plugin that would support menu ancestry?

---

Edit

I feel like I'm right there, but missing one thing...

```
function getUrl() {
      $url  = @( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] :  'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
      $url .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] !== 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
      $url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      return $url;
    }
    function getDir($foo) {
        $url = $foo;
        $info = parse_url($url);
        $dir = dirname($info["path"]);
        return $dir;
    }
    function wpa83498_nav_class( $classes, $item ){
        // if Shop is the current menu item being output
        // and we're viewing a single product post type
        $currentDirPath = getDir(getUrl());
        if( ('Sales' == $item->title && is_singular( 'product' )) || (parse_url($item->url, PHP_URL_PATH) == $currentDirPath && is_singular( 'product' )) )
            $classes[] = 'current-page-ancestor';
        return $classes;
    }
    add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpa83498_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the final solution I came up with. I spent a lot of looking into whether I could change the the custom post type "product" to hierarchical and set its page parent appropriately so that the menus would add the correct ancestor classes naturally. But I hit a road block and eventually came back to a solution based on the new permalink.

So I imagine this should work for *anyone* who is aiming to fake a page parent hierarchy when using custom permalinks.

We get the current page url (set by the custom permalinks plugin), then strip it down to the path and save it as the `$currentDirPath` variable. Then we evaluate whether a menu item's url path is contained within the `$currentDirPath`, and if so we add the `current-page-ancestor` class.

```
function getUrl() {
  $url  = @( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] :  'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
  $url .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] !== 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
  $url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  return $url;
}
function getDir($foo) {
    $url = $foo;
    $info = parse_url($url);
    $dir = dirname($info["path"]);
    return $dir;
}
function wpa83498_nav_class( $classes, $item ){
    $currentDirPath = getDir(getUrl());
    if( (strpos($currentDirPath,(parse_url($item->url, PHP_URL_PATH))) !== false) && is_singular( 'product' ) )
        $classes[] = 'current-page-ancestor';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpa83498_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add classes to `wp_nav_menu` via the [nav_menu_css_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class) filter:

```
function wpa83498_nav_class( $classes, $item ){
    // if Shop is the current menu item being output
    // and we're viewing a single product post type
    if( 'Shop' == $item->title && is_singular( 'product' ) )
        $classes[] = 'current-page-ancestor';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpa83498_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

**EDIT-**

Try this to see how the objects that make up a menu are constructed. Perhaps it will shed some light on how you can manipulate menu output. Look at things like `menu_item_parent` and `object_id` to see how menu items are related to each other and the posts / pages they represent. Warning- do not do this on a live site!

```
function wpa_inspect_menu_objects( $menu ) {    
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $menu );
    echo '</pre>';  
    die();  
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects' , 'wpa_inspect_menu_objects' );
```

Comment: Okay, so that worked well (although I'm not 100% clear how). But I'd like to add another step if I may. This may be another part of the function. Am I able to add `current-page-ancestor` to a menu list item based upon different sub-parent pages. e.g. website.com/shop/new/product and website.com/shop/used/product. Where the menu would have `Shop -> New | Used` and the individual product page would determine whether New or Used got the `current-page-ancestor` class? Hope that's clear!

Comment: for that you'd probably want either the `nav_menu_objects` filter, a [custom walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class), or to build the menu manually via [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items). See my edit above for some code that will maybe help you understand how WordPress stores menu items and builds the menu.

Comment: another thought - if you're adding items to a nav menu, WP should be inserting the proper parent / ancestor classes if the items are children in the nav menu, regardless of whether or not they're actually related to each other naturally.

Comment: I understand now how the menus are built and why your code works, so thank you for that inspector code. To your second thought: the product children aren't part of the menu, only the parents are (i.e. 'Shop' and 'New'|'Used'). I believe Wordpress is having troubling recognizing the product pages as children because they have custom permalinks and their original parent is an entirely different page. Is there some way to hook into the new permalink to get a value that might match one of the menu item titles?

Comment: Do you have a piece of 'inspector' code that will let me see the post object for the current product page so perhaps I can find a value that will help me select which menu item it is a part of? Just like the code you gave me to see the menu construction.

Comment: NM, found the code to print the $post variables. The page_parent is set to 0, so there is my problem. But there is no Parent Page field to edit in the custom 'product' post backend. Is there a filter I can apply to add that option?

Comment: ah, I see, your products aren't actually in the menu. making them a child of a page won't add the classes to the menu, as those classes are added based on the parent/child relationship *in the menu*. i'll have to think about how to efficiently achieve what you're after.

Comment: So I made some edits to come up with what _should_ be working to add menu classes. Essentially I'm evaluating whether the $item->url is equivalent to the current url's directory path. Current-page-ancestor classes aren't being added yet, so I'm still missing something. See edit above.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, @Milo. With your input I was able to come up with a flexible solution that I hope helps others too!